# Webpack 4 and react loadable does not seems to create correct chunk for server side rendering

Tags: reactjs, webpack, lazy-loading, webpack-4

I am trying to create an ssr react app with lazy loading import.
Everything works fine except it **does not fetch all the required chunks**.

I am also wondering if this is related to a dynamic component, which is base on server response

**Edit - It actually renders all the required chunks but it wipes out the whole thing when client-side takes over and renders again**

Since it re-renders all it slows down by a lot.

[image]

The parser happens on server-side and when client-side takes over it fetches more
**server.js**

```
 const history = createHistory({
    initialEntries: [urlPath],
  })
  // const history = createHistory()
  const store = configureStore(history, {
    location: {
        ...
    },

  })

  const context = {}
  const htmlRoot = (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <StaticRouter location={urlPath} context={context}>
        <AppRoot />
      </StaticRouter>
    </Provider>
  )

  // pre fetching data from api
  store
    .runSaga(rootSaga)
    .done.then(() => {

        const RTS = renderToString(htmlRoot) + printDrainHydrateMarks()
        const head = Helmet.renderStatic() 
        console.log(printDrainHydrateMarks())

        res.status(code).send(renderDom(RTS, port, host, storeState, head))
      }
    })
    .catch(e => {
      console.log(e.message)
      res.status(500).send(e.message)
    })

  renderToString(htmlRoot)
  console.log(printDrainHydrateMarks())

  store.close()
} else {
  res.status(500).send(_err)
}
```

**Prod Server**

```
Loadable.preloadAll().then(() => {
  app.listen(PROD_PORT, (error) => {

  })
});
```

**Client side**

```
Loadable.preloadReady().then(() => {
    hydrate(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
          <AppRoot />
        </ConnectedRouter>
      </Provider>,
      domRoot,
    )
  })
```

**Split Chunks setup**

```
    styles: {
      name: 'styles',
      test: /\.css$/,
      chunks: 'all',
      enforce: true
    },
```

Any opinion or advice is welcome please

Someone suggested to try with window.onload = () => {  but this approach seems slow down as well.

Comment: Good questions. But i still do not have any idea.

Answer (score 2):

You should use ReactLoadablePlugin to have a list of loadable imports:

```
new ReactLoadablePlugin({
  filename: './build/react-loadable.json',
})
```

Using "react loadable capture", you can find out which dynamic components are needed while rendering and you can add their bundles to your header file:

```
const content = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
  <Loadable.Capture report={moduleName => modules.push(moduleName)}>
    <Provider store={configureStore()}>
      <StaticRouter location={req.url} context={context}>
        <App />
      </StaticRouter>

    </Provider>
  </Loadable.Capture>
);

  let bundles = getBundles(stats, modules);
  bundles.map((item) => {
      //add js to header
      })
```

This prevents react loadable from wiping out the content and rerendering it.

To config the Webpack to output right chunk based on dynamically loaded component do this:

```
 optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
          default: false,
          vendors: false,
      }
  }
}
```

This configuration works for me in Webpack v4.

You can find a complete documentation to work with React loadable server-side rendering here:

https://github.com/jamiebuilds/react-loadable

Answer (score 0):

I am using route-centric code splitting with [react-universal-component](https://github.com/faceyspacey/react-universal-component) and [flush chuck](https://github.com/faceyspacey/webpack-flush-chunks). Sorry for the long code snippet/pseudo code, I have tried my best to make it shorter. :)

First build an array for react router mapping corresponding components

```
let routeConfig = [
  {path: '/foo', component: 'Foo'},
  {path: '/bar', component: 'Bar'}
];
```

`universal` function make sure the component and its children can be correctly imported on both server side and client side. It's smart enough to lazy load the split codes accordingly.

```
import universal from 'react-universal-component';
const routes = routeConfig.map((item) =>{
  let route = {};
  route.path = item.path;
  route.component = universal(import(`./container/${item.component}`), options);
  return route;
});
```

Render the router in React Component.

```
class App extends React.Component {
 render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Switch>
          {routes.map( route => <Route key={ route.path } { ...route } />)}
        </Switch>
      </div>
);}}
```

Config webpack define the code splitting names.

```
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    chunkFilename: '[name].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist/client'),
    publicPath: '/xxxxxx/'
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      // Options similar to the same options in webpackOptions.output
      // both options are optional
      filename: '[name].css',
      chunkFilename: '[id].css'
  })],
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      chunks: 'initial',
      cacheGroups: {
        vendors: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/, 
          name: 'vendor' // bundle all the npm module as vendor.js
}}}}
```

Finally, the `server.js` will use [flush chuck](https://github.com/faceyspacey/webpack-flush-chunks) to do the code splitting.

```
const chunkNames = flushChunkNames();
const {js, styles, cssHash, scripts, stylesheets} = flushChunks(clientStats, {chunkNames});
res.send(`<!doctype html>
  <html>
    <head>
      ${styles}
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="root">${app}</div>
      ${cssHash}
      ${js}
    </body>
  </html>`);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using ReactLoadableSSRAddon, it works better than the plugin provided by ReactLoadable [see this link for further info](https://github.com/themgoncalves/react-loadable-ssr-addon). In my case it made a huge difference !

Answer (score 0):

if you are using ts-loader try setting:

tsconfig.json

```
{
  .
  .
  .

  "module" : "esnext",
  "moduleResolution": "Node",
  .
  .
  .
}
```